# '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType' Overlapping Check

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Hi I am getting this error in my validation check

```
def sefl(clean):

  start_number=self.cleaned_data.get("start_number",None)
  end_number=self.cleaned_data.get("end_number",None)
  latest_start=max(start_number, end_number)
  earliest_end = min(start_number, end_number)
  delta = (earliest_end - latest_start) + 1
  if delta is None:
        raise ValidationError("overlap not allowed")
```

Comment: You need to handle `None` values because they cannot be compared to numbers.

Comment: @Thomas please can you help me to do that

Comment: Both `start_number` and `end_number` are `None`, you can't compare those.

Comment: This code, as written, will fail long before any `None`s get involved; it takes no `self` parameter yet tries to access `self`. Post an actual [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem; if you cut it down to something that demonstrates some other, unrelated problem(s), you're not helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to catch the none values you are creating, like this:

```
def sefl(clean):
  start_number = self.cleaned_data.get("start_number", None)
  end_number = self.cleaned_data.get("end_number", None)
  if start_number is not None and end_number is not None:
      latest_start=max(start_number, end_number)
      earliest_end = min(start_number, end_bbch)
      delta = (earliest_end - latest_start) + 1
      if delta is None:
            raise ValidationError("overlap not allowed")
  else:
      raise ValidationError("start_number and end_number are required")
```

This is because you are defining the default values for both variables to `None`. If at least one of them is actually `None` at the time of the comparison that `max` or `min` do, the issue you are encountering is raised.

There are a couple of ways around this, if you are interested. For example you could use a different default value instead of `None`, if there is a suitable value for that.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but this code is not validating overlapping.

Comment: Well, if there are no latest_start and earliest end time, then there is no delta. So yes this code doesn't validate, if there are no values.

Comment: with running this code i am not sure this code actually checking overlapping